# How to store values in an array Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arraylist

I have a function:

```
  chatManager.connect()

  .then(currentUser => {

    var final = currentUser.users;
    var name = [];
    var arr = [];

    $.each(final,function(index,val){

      if(val.name != '{{Auth::user()->name}}')
      {
        console.log(val.id);        //Harry, Ron (each in different line)

        arr = name.push(val.id)

        console.log(arr);   //1,2 (each in different line)

        var presence = val.presenceStore.store.{{Auth::user()->name}}{{Auth::user()->id}}

      }

    });
```

I want the arr to be an array like [Harry,Ron]. Why is it not working? I am new to Jquery. Please help.

Comment: what is the type of val.id? Does val.id returns Harry, Ron?

Comment: `arr.push(val.id)` (also not a jQuery issue at all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr = name.push(val.id)` is your problem. [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the array's new length, not an array. Simply replace the line with

```
arr.push(val.id);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But, when I use `arr.push(val.id)`. I am also using push here. So, what is the difference?

Comment: @Rob The difference is explained in the first sentence of this answer. You are never actually pushing anything into `arr`.

Comment: Thnx for the help.